# VideoView show on GLSurfaceView?

Tags: android-videoview, glsurfaceview

recently,I'm doing android development,there have been a question that always confused me for a long time.I want to show VideoView on GLSurfaceView, my code is as following:

```
   setContentView(glSurfaceView,new LayoutParams( 
                           LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                           LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)); 
   videoView= View.inflate(QCARSampleActivity.this, R.layout.main, null);
   addContentView(videoView, new LayoutParams(    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
   mVideoView = (VideoView) overlayView.findViewById(R.id.mVideoView);
```

code of playing video is as following:

```
                    videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);        
                    mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
                    mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
                    mVideoView.requestFocus();
                    mVideoView.start();
```

when I run it,it works ok,but only hear sound,can't see video,why? please?

Answer (score 3):

Try This:

```
mVideoView.setZOrderOnTop( true );
```